# Typescript: declare function for existing class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use this plugin [this plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck) with typescript (together with Angular 2 and Angular CLI).

I have to init some elements like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('i-checks')).forEach(function(item) {
        item.iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
        });
    });
```

Unfortunately typescript throws an error because he cannot find `iCheck()`.

```
Module build failed: Error: /../my/path.ts (39,13): Unterminated string literal.
/../my/path.ts (35,18): Property 'iCheck' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

How can I tell typescript to ignore this error?

The necessary CSS and JS files for the plugin I have included in the `index.html`. So I think it should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1) install the plugin:

```
npm i -S icheck
```

2) copy the reference to angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/icheck/icheck.js"]
```

3) on typings.d.ts:

```
  declare ... function or what you need from icheck
```